# Different balances in API block explorers for BTC

Tags: blockchain, api, block

BTC.com block explorer shows bigger balance than for example Insight or Blockchair. For example: https://btc.com/1FLDCfr9iG7n6bAdGsqBXmhaLgC4aSze72

https://insight.bitpay.com/address/1FLDCfr9iG7n6bAdGsqBXmhaLgC4aSze72 https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/1FLDCfr9iG7n6bAdGsqBXmhaLgC4aSze72

Why BTC.com's result is different?

Comment: These explorers are running different code, and without seeing the code is very difficult to know why they are different

Answer (score 0):

Just check on our explorer 
https://bitaps.com/1FLDCfr9iG7n6bAdGsqBXmhaLgC4aSze72

Correct balance is 1.41297880BTC

You can also turn timeline mode and check balance change after each transaction

[image]